# GoogleMock, Return by out parameter and normal return, consume array

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I am mocking a low level interface for reading serial data. This interface has a public function for reading bytes from its internal buffer. I want to mock this interface so I can return a sequence of bytes and for each byte returned also return the value `true`. Once it is out of bytes to read the function must return `false`

What I am doing now is the following:

```
struct IUart
{
    virtual bool Read(uint8_t& value) = 0;
    //... other functions
};

struct MockUart: IUart
{
    MOCK_METHOD1(Read, bool(uint8_t&));
    //... other functions
};

struct TestMyTest: ::testing::Test
{
    /* Setting up test fixture */
};

TEST_F(TestMyTest, TestMyMockedInterface)
{
    MockUart uartMock;

    EXPECT_CALL(uartMock, Read(::testing::_))
        .WillOnce(::testing::DoAll(::testing::SetArgReferee<0>(10), ::testing::Return(true)))
        .WillOnce(::testing::DoAll(::testing::SetArgReferee<0>(11), ::testing::Return(true)))
        .WillOnce(::testing::DoAll(::testing::SetArgReferee<0>(12), ::testing::Return(true)))
        .WillOnce(::testing::Return(false));

    //... etc
}
```

Is there some other way that this can be facilitated? Is there some kidn of `::testing::WithNextValueFromArray` option available?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing like what you've described available "out of the box" in Google Mock, but you could write your own action to achieve this.  However, there are several ways you could go about this:

### Option 1

Write an action that does almost exactly what you've described:

```
ACTION_TEMPLATE(SetArgWithNextValueFromArray,
                HAS_1_TEMPLATE_PARAMS(int, k),
                AND_1_VALUE_PARAMS(results))
{
    ::testing::get<k>(args) = results->front();
    results->erase(results->begin());
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
TEST_F(TestMyTest, TestMyMockedInterface)
{
    MockUart uartMock;
    std::vector<uint8_t> results = { 10, 11, 12 };

    EXPECT_CALL(uartMock, Read(::testing::_))
        .WillOnce(::testing::DoAll(SetArgWithNextValueFromArray<0>(&results),::testing::Return(true)))
        .WillOnce(::testing::DoAll(SetArgWithNextValueFromArray<0>(&results),::testing::Return(true)))
        .WillOnce(::testing::DoAll(SetArgWithNextValueFromArray<0>(&results),::testing::Return(true)))
        .WillOnce(::testing::Return(false));
}
```

This action has the advantage of being reusable with other tests, but it's still somewhat verbose.

## Option 2

Write an action that emulates reading successfully from the UART:

```
ACTION_P(ReadSuccessfully, results)
{
    arg0 = results->front();
    results->erase(results->begin());
    return true;
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
TEST_F(TestMyTest, TestMyMockedInterface)
{
    MockUart uartMock;
    std::vector<uint8_t> results = { 10, 11, 12 };

    EXPECT_CALL(uartMock, Read(::testing::_))
        .WillOnce(ReadSuccessfully(&results))
        .WillOnce(ReadSuccessfully(&results))
        .WillOnce(ReadSuccessfully(&results))
        .WillOnce(::testing::Return(false));
}
```

This action is less reusable, but less verbose.

## Option 3

Write an action that emulates reading from the UART:

```
ACTION_P(FakeRead, results)
{
    if (results->empty())
    {
        return false;
    }
    arg0 = results->front();
    results->erase(results->begin());
    return true;
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
TEST_F(TestMyTest, TestMyMockedInterface)
{
    MockUart uartMock;
    std::vector<uint8_t> results = { 10, 11, 12 };

    EXPECT_CALL(uartMock, Read(::testing::_)).WillRepeatedly(FakeRead(&results));
}
```

This action is also not very reusable, but is the least verbose.  The action has a complete fake implementation of `Read`, which can be useful for some of your tests.  On the other hand, a complete fake implementation may itself be buggy, which can adversely affect your tests.

There may be other options, but these should hopefully provide enough examples of what can be achieved.

Comment: I had already found out indeed that I could also use `WillRepeatedly(Invoke([&](uint8_t& c){ /* option 3 impl; */}))` But was having the same "thoughts" about the fake stuff introducing bugs in the test code. So I hoped something out of the box (tested) by google was available. ATM I've gone for the very explicit version, (what's in the OP)